# Are smart contract constructor arguments hidden?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I want to know if it's possible to decode a smart contracts creation arguments.

I know that if you are calling a normal function of a contract, you can decode the arguments provided if you have access to the ABI (or know the functions arguments)

Is the same possible with the contract constructor arguments?

The reason I want to know this is because I want to create a private seed that will help with random number generation.

I have also heard that you don't even need to include the constructor part of the code in the Etherscan verification process, but I'm not sure if that is true.

Answer (score 2):

no, everything in smart contract is public and viewed by everyone. The arguments in creation of smart contract is public and viewed by everyone, even private variables can be accessed inside the smart contract. If you verify any smart contract on etherscan, you have to provide constructor arguments to verify it. It is never recommended to store any private information inside smart contract